# already mount the shared folder but not show up vagrant

Tags: vagrant, shared-directory

I have configured shared folder in the vagrant file

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
 config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise64"
 config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant_data",type:"virtualbox"
end
```

And after running vagrant up, it shows that the shared folder has been mounted.

```
Mounting shared folders...
/vagrant => C:/Users/sued/.vagrant.d/boxes/precise64
```

But I can not see the created shared folder in the guest machine. Nothing happend.

Answer (score 1):

It worked when I manually mounted the shared folder, as explained e.g. [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/674974/how-to-mount-a-virtualbox-shared-folder).

But more importantly, I run the base box (the box located in the `.vagrant.d/boxes/precise64` folder). I needed to create a new `Vagrantfile` in a different folder and start the vm via `vagrant up`. If you do it this way, the shared folders are working automatically.